# Changes in /usr/bin and /usr/sbin reverted after reboot

Tags: linux, nas

I'm not really good with Linux and I don't understand why my custom scripts are gone when I reboot my machine. I added my scripts into `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` folders. After reboot these folders look just as if they were recreated from some image, or something.

What I am using is Thecus n5550 Linux-based NAS. This is output of `uname -rs`

```
 Linux 3.4.73
```

and here's `df` (size info cut off)

```
Filesystem   Use% Mounted on
/dev/root     40% /
tmpfs         10% /dev/shm
tmpfs         10% /var
/dev/loop0    55% /rom
/dev/loop1   100% /img
/dev/loop2   100% /usr/lib64
/dev/loop3   100% /usr/share/zoneinfo
/dev/loop4   100% /opt
/dev/sdaaa4    3% /syslog
/dev/sdaaa2    4% /etc
/dev/md50      5% /raidsys/0
/dev/md0       51% /raid0
```

What am I doing wrong?

`mount` output:

```
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
/dev/root on / type ext2 (rw,relatime,errors=continue)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /var type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rom type ext2 (ro,noatime,nodiratime,errors=continue)
/dev/loop1 on /img type squashfs (ro,relatime)
/dev/loop2 on /usr/lib64 type squashfs (ro,relatime)
/dev/loop3 on /usr/share/zoneinfo type squashfs (ro,relatime)
/dev/loop4 on /opt type squashfs (ro,relatime)
/dev/sdaaa4 on /syslog type ext2 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,errors=continue)
/dev/sdaaa2 on /etc type ext2 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,errors=continue)
/dev/md50 on /raidsys/0 type xfs (rw,noatime,attr2,noquota)
/dev/md0 on /raid0 type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,nobarrier,errors=remount-ro,data=writeback)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw,relatime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be using `/usr/local/bin/` and `/usr/local/sbin/`, as these are meant for local modifications.

Please check `man hier` for further details.

Comment: I did that in the first place I was really surprised they vanished after NAS restart :/ Btw, the same happens to my crontab

Comment: at a guess, it's probably loading your root filesystem from an image clean each boot, and what you're seeing is a ramdisk or such, so it's all volatile data lost upon reboot. You might have to look into the documentation for the NAS or ask them. They'll likely be doing something hinky though.

Comment: ya, from https://forum.thecus.com/archive/index.php?thread-12938.html hinky-ness confirmed. You'll need to see if there's a way to write to wherever they are loading the initial image from.

Comment: nice find. I registered to that forum lately and sill awaiting for moderation to grant me permission to create questions (sic!)